# Will I have a problem buying a large bank draft with wrong address on my ID?

Tags: canada, banking

I'm in the middle of a cash real estate purchase and will need a fairly large (close to $100k) bank draft in the next few days. I just realized the address on my photo ID is out of date, and my bank has my current address.

Should I expect the bank to request my photo ID when purchasing the draft, and if so would a mismatch on the address be a barrier?

The funds are in my chequeing account at said bank, so I can verify my identity with my PIN, and as the valid account holder I expect I could answer any other verification questions they might have.

Comment: Sounds like a question best answered by your bank.

Comment: Were you with the bank when you were at the old address (the one that appears on the ID)? If they can see the ID-verified address in their records, that could well help.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the bank what alternate ID they will accept if there is a mismatch in the information on the standard ID and the information on your bank account.

There is always a mismatch in address information when moving. The organization that issues the ID can want you to provide proof that you live there by providing a bill that was delivered to your house, but that requires that at least one company accept your change of address.

Sometimes they will ask for any other ID that you have that has your picture and address, or some combination of information. That could include a passport, or birth certificate.

To get a hint about what they will accept they might have information on their website that shows what forms of ID they require when opening a new account.